# GUI application that changes background with button

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to create a Java GUI application that contains a label and button. When the button is clicked the background color of the first panel is changed. I've got the label and button but getting errors whenever I click the button. Also, I wanted the first panel to originally have a yellow background then switch to whatever color. Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ChangeDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
public static final int WIDTH = 300;
public static final int HEIGHT= 200;
private JPanel biggerPanel;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ChangeDemo gui = new ChangeDemo();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}

public ChangeDemo()
{
    super ("ChangeBackgroundDemo");
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));      

    JPanel biggerPanel = new JPanel();
    biggerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    biggerPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    JLabel namePanel = new JLabel("Click the button to change the background color");
    biggerPanel.add(namePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    add(namePanel);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    JButton changeButton = new JButton("Change Color");
    changeButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(changeButton);

    add(buttonPanel); 
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String buttonString = e.getActionCommand();

    if(buttonString.equals("Change Color"))
        biggerPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);            
    else
        System.out.println("Unexpected Error!");
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo based on amendments to your code, haven't had time to tidy it up but hopefully you'll get the gist of it. Problem was you hand't added Panels to the borders (north, south etc.) in order to color them. Hopefully this helps.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ChangeDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
public static final int WIDTH = 300;
public static final int HEIGHT= 200;
private JPanel biggerPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ChangeDemo gui = new ChangeDemo();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}

public ChangeDemo()
{
super ("ChangeBackgroundDemo");
setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));      

//JPanel biggerPanel = new JPanel();
this.biggerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.biggerPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Click the button to change the background color");
namePanel.add(nameLabel);
namePanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
//this.biggerPanel.add(namePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


add(namePanel);
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

JButton changeButton = new JButton("Change Color");
changeButton.addActionListener(this);
changeButton.setActionCommand("Change Color");
buttonPanel.add(changeButton);

add(buttonPanel); 
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String buttonString = e.getActionCommand();
        if(buttonString.equals("Change Color"))
            this.namePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);            
        else
        System.out.println("Unexpected Error!");
}

}
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. still coming up with errors when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code.

First, you must start a Swing application with a call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ChangeDemo());
}
```

Second, you use Swing components. You only extend a Swing component when you want to override a method of the Swing component.

Third, I made a action listener specifically for your JButton.  That way, you don't have to check for a particular JButton string.  You can create as many action listeners as you need for your GUI.

```
    JButton changeButton = new JButton("Change Color");
    changeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            isYellow = !isYellow;

            if (isYellow) buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            else buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Finally, I changed the background color of the JButton panel.

Here's the entire ChangeDemo class.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ChangeDemo implements Runnable {

    private boolean isYellow;

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ChangeDemo());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Change Background Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(
                "Click the button to change the background color");
        nameLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        namePanel.add(nameLabel);

        mainPanel.add(namePanel);

        final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        isYellow = true;

        JButton changeButton = new JButton("Change Color");
        changeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                isYellow = !isYellow;

                if (isYellow) buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                else buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(changeButton);

        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```